# ThreadLocal vs local variable in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, local

What is the difference between this ThreadName and LocalName in the code below? Are they both ThreadLocal?

```
// Thread-Local variable that yields a name for a thread
ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
{
    return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
});

// Action that prints out ThreadName for the current thread
Action action = () =>
{
    // If ThreadName.IsValueCreated is true, it means that we are not the 
    // first action to run on this thread. 
    bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;
    String LocalName = "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1} {2}", ThreadName.Value, repeat ? "(repeat)" : "", LocalName);
};

// Launch eight of them.  On 4 cores or less, you should see some repeat ThreadNames
Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action);

// Dispose when you are done
ThreadName.Dispose();
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `ThreadLocal<T>`?

Comment: `string LocalName` is very ThreadLocal. As long as it's not closed-over by a lambda.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, that is why I came with this question. the example is modified from the sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet - did you? The MSDN page I found only has _"Provides thread-local storage of data."_ (and member specs and an example).

Comment: @Helic - but I don't get the comparison with a local var. It is functionally closer to `static`.

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread Gets the currently running thread... as Henk implies... ThreadLocal is evaluated lazily so beware. Investigate  Thread.GetData and Thread.SetData... This may interest you http://theburningmonk.com/2010/10/threadstatic-vs-threadlocal/

Comment: See the answers to related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202735/what-are-the-advantages-of-instance-level-thread-local-storage

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Ick, that's really not very good. Still, the question would be better having stated that: "I've tried reading the documentation (here) and I don't understand X"...

Answer (score 3):

`LocalName` is not thread-local. It is scoped to the execution of the surrounding lambda. You will get a fresh value each time the lambda runs (and concurrent runs are independent). With a `ThreadLocal` you get a fresh value *per thread*. Repeatedly invoking `ThreadName.Value` will only give you one value if it happens to be on the same thread.

In this example both are equivalent because `Thread.ManagedThreadId` is also thread-local. Try `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: The values are equal but they're not equivalent. ThreadName is reused by thread pool in Parallel.Invoke.

Comment: @norekhov Not sure what you're saying. Here, `ThreadName` always hands out the same value that `LocalName` also has.

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread pool. So if a thread is resused for a second action you will get "repeat".
LocalName is a local variable.