# Is it possible for a managed thread to have a Race Condition with itself

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

So in order to have a separate context for each thread that the program is running I set up a Context - Thread mapping class as follows

```
      public class ContextMap : IContextMap
{
    private static IContextMap _contextMap;
    private Dictionary<int, IArbContext2> ContextDict;
    private static string DbName;
    private ContextMap()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DbName))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Setup must be called before accessing ContextMap");
        ContextDict = new Dictionary<int, IArbContext2>();
    }

    protected internal static void Setup(IContextMap map)
    {
        _contextMap = map;
    }

    public static void Setup(string dbName)
    {
        DbName = dbName;
    }

    public static IContextMap GetInstance()
    {
        return _contextMap ?? (_contextMap = new ContextMap());
    }


    public IArbContext2 GetOrCreateContext()
    {
        var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        if(!ContextDict.ContainsKey(threadId))
            ContextDict.Add(threadId,new ArbContext(DbName));
        return ContextDict[threadId];
    }

    public void DestroyContext()
    {
        if (ContextDict.ContainsKey(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
            ContextDict.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

Somehow the code is (very rarely but still happening) throwing a keynotfound exception in the GetOrCreateContext method. Is it possible for a thread to be sidetracked to a separate action (e.g. the overseeing thread forces it to do another action that causes the thread to call DestroyContext after it checked if the Dict had the key but before it returned it) and then to resume where it left off. I never specifically do this but I can't understand any other reason how this error is being thrown.

Thank You.

Comment: You are not showing how one calls `GetOrCreateContext` and `DestroyContext`. Possibly it called from multiple threads without appropriate synchronization... Side note: from what I can see you are re-implementing thread local storage ([SO Q:ThreadLocal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158981/does-c-sharp-have-a-threadlocal-analog-for-data-members-to-the-threadstatic) as starting point).

Comment: It wouldnt make a dif as can be seen in the code the contexts are created and stored by the thread id its impossible for any thread to affect any context that it doesn't own

Comment: If there is no more than one thread involved what you're talking is not possible

Comment: The problem you encounter is quite possibly simultaneous access to the dictionary by different threads. Note that Dictionary<K,T> is not thread-safe, and simultaneous accesses (especially when it involves modifiying the dictionary) can result in undefined behaviour (aka, red herrings). Surround the dictionary accesses with `lock` (just to name one possibility)...

Comment: In addition to what Alexi said, if you are doing any work with ThreadPools (even behind the sciences like by using async/await) it is very possible that a continuous block of code could start on one thread but then continue on another thread.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  -noted, What I didn't show is that whenever a context is referened in any class its done via a property like this IArbContext2 context {get{return ContextMap.GetOrCreateContext();} I specifically did this so that the code can be changing threads and it wouldn't matter because each thread when calling would only receive its context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `Dictionary` is not thread-safe. There can be unexpected behaviour when multiple threads try to access it, even if they are all using unique keys, because creating or removing a key/value pair is not an atomic action.

The easiest fix would be to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` in its place for `ContextDict`

Comment: +1. Note that the actual problem is OP does not see the issue of multithreaded access to `Dictionary` as a problem.

Comment: Thanks For the answers. I figured that as long as there was controlled access I would need to take any precautions - especially since there wasn't any race conditions between threads. I'll implement this and see if the problem stops.

Comment: @Alex Right. You can find information on this, e.g. here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/021a235b-b930-460a-b093-72acbacbb97d/generic-dictionary-operations-and-threadingis-read-and-write-lock-necessary-if-not-enumerating?forum=netfxbcl There's probably plenty of articles on it. Various optimizations, etc. under the hood mean that it's not just as simple as ensuring the keys are different

Comment: Thank You, Can't up-vote you all yet (apparently i'd need 15 points) but I truly appreciate all of you taking the time to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Answering your literal question, *NOT* attempting to solve your problem.  (@BenAaronsom has already done that.)

No:  You have a "race condition" when the result of some computation depends on the order in which two or more threads access the same variable.  If there is only one thread running in the race, then no matter how many times you run it, the same thread will always win.  If a single-threaded program gives a non-deterministic answer, then whatever the problem is, it's not a race condition.

Comment: Purely theoretical... but couldn't it be done if you are using a callback system

Comment: @Alex, There are ways for a single-threaded program to produce a non-deterministic result, and there are lots of ways for it to produce an unexpected result, but I would not call any of them _race_ condition.  I would not call it "race condition" unless there are two or more racers (threads) and the outcome/behavior/final-state depends on which one wins the race.