# Creating a value that is shared between a thread and all its children

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to create a shared value in a static class, that each thread can set for itself.
When it is set, it will be the same for all of its children.
If one if the children sets it, it won't affect the parent or other children of the parent.

Here is some example code to hopefully help you examplify:

```
static class MyClass
{
    public int Prop
    {
        get => ???;
        set => ???;
    }
}

static int Do()
{
    return MyClass.Prop;
}

static void First()
{
    MyClass.Prop = 1;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>  Do()); // Always is 1
}

static void Second()
{
    MyClass.Prop = 2;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>  Do()); // Always is 2
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass.Prop = 0;
    Parallel.Invoke(First, Second);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>  Do()); // Always is 0
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C# have a "ThreadLocal" analog (for data members) to the "ThreadStatic" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158981/does-c-sharp-have-a-threadlocal-analog-for-data-members-to-the-threadstatic)

Comment: Is that you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal ? One variable, one value per thread. But what do you call *childrens* ? Do you need the value be shared between a subtree of a tree and not be different for every node ? In this case I think you need to implement that or search the web if such thing exists...

Comment: Make `Do()` and `Prop` non-static?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please fix it.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Yes, I need the subtree of children to have the same value, I wanted to know if something like this exists, hense the question.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov of course it doesn't - it's missing the get{} and set{} because I don't know how to implement them in the way that i need

Comment: Charlieface - I can't, and also I can't have Do() accept any extra parameters.

Comment: IMHO you should edit the question and clarify what "children" and "parent" stands for. I can't see any representation of a parent-child relationship in the code you provided.

Comment: `QueueUserWorkItem` call does not compile. `return MyClass.Prop` does not compile. Fix it now. And you will get an answer.